# devpi - pip install setup.cfg MissingSectionHeaderError - virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, devpi

I have a really simply python package which I'm building/uploading to a devpi repo running on my laptop.

When I attempt to pip install it I get the following error:

```
MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: setup.cfg, line: 1
'[\n'
```

My package doesn't even have a setup.cfg file, so I'm a bit confused.  Does anyone have any idea on what's going on?

**Update1:**
I've since discovered that trying to pip install *any* package I get the exact same error, making me think this has nothing to do with my package, but more likely to do with my devpi configuration or devpi and/or pip related dotfiles

**Update2:**
Hmm, perhaps this is the problem.  the devpi site mentions there being an issue with devpi 4.0 and pip 1.8.2, both of which I have installed.  I'll have to look into this.

[pip doesn’t install packages anymore with devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/announce/server-4.0.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had any issues after I downgraded the pip versions in all my virtualenvs from `pip==1.8.2` to `pip==8.1.1`